# Azure Active Directory Web Api not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am creating a mobile application and a web api. The mobile app will access the web api using the token obtained.

I have created a mobile application using the portal "https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/" and a Web App/API using the Applications under Azure Active Directory.
Both these were created using a Global admin of the tenant.

When I try to login into the mobile app, with the App Id of the web api as scope, I am getting below error.

> The application named [ABC] was not found in the tenant named [XYZ].onmicrosoft.com

The native client is not able to find the web api.

Any pointers on what could be the problem here ?

Comment: I also tried creating the native application [here](https://portal.azure.com) under App Registrations and adding the permissions for web api to the native client application. But when I run the application in mobile, I get the error  
**The application [DEF] is not supported for this API version.**

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK , currently you can't call web api which protected by Azure AD V1.0 endpoint from client app app that uses the v2.0 endpoint in the [Microsoft Application Registration Portal.](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/)  You could create the client app in azure portal under App Registrations, and add/grant permission to access your web api app .

The error `The application [DEF] is not supported for this API version` could be reproduced by using v2.0 endpoints to acquire token in azure ad v1.0 app:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

You should create requests to below endpoints in azure ad v1.0 app(register in azure portal):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize (single tenant)
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token(single tenant)
```

And set `resource` parameter ,the App ID URI of the web API (secured resource)) in your scenario, when acquiring token for your web api . Please check these [code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-code-samples#native-application-to-web-api) for how to call web api in native app in azure ad